# How to set the maxFlightTime in a flight offers search with the Amadeus API?

Tags: amadeus

I am making a POST to the Amadeus API for flight offers.

I am trying to set the maxFlightTime parameter.

The API documentation says:

> maxFlightTime number example: 200  This option allows to modify the
> value for the Elapsed Flying Time (EFT) masterPricer option

- https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/air/api-doc/flight-offers-search/api-reference

My question is:
What does this parameter expect? The documentation says a number and provides 200 as an example.

What does the number represent? Is it minutes, hours, or something different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`maxFlightTime` is a bit complex to use. The number is a percentage expressing how much longer the flight offers you want to find can be compared to the shortest flight that exists for these search criteria.

Let's take an example:
We are looking for a flight from `MAD` to `SFO` (and we are returning only 1 offer for the sake of the example) using the POST endpoint of Flight Offers Search:

JSON Body:

```json
{
    "currencyCode": "EUR",
    "originDestinations": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "originLocationCode": "MAD",
            "destinationLocationCode": "SFO",
            "departureDateTimeRange": {
                "date": "2021-05-01",
                "time": "10:00:00"
            }
        }
    ],
    "travelers": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "travelerType": "ADULT",
            "fareOptions": [
                "STANDARD"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "sources": [
        "GDS"
    ],
    "searchCriteria": {
        "maxFlightOffers": 1,
        "flightFilters": {
            "cabinRestrictions": [
                {
                    "cabin": "ECONOMY",
                    "coverage": "MOST_SEGMENTS",
                    "originDestinationIds": [
                        "1"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

If you check the JSON response you will see that the offer is `MAD` to `IST` (duration `PT4H15M` so 4h15) and `IST` to `SFO` (duration `PT13H20M` so 13h20M) so in total duration of 17h35. Note that this API always returns the cheapest flight offers for the given criteria.

If now we want to do the same request adding `maxFlightTime` but we don't want to have such a long trip, we want to have a maximum total duration of 110% longer than the shortest flight available.

We can use this JSON body

```json
{
    "currencyCode": "EUR",
    "originDestinations": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "originLocationCode": "MAD",
            "destinationLocationCode": "SFO",
            "departureDateTimeRange": {
                "date": "2021-05-01",
                "time": "10:00:00"
            }
        }
    ],
    "travelers": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "travelerType": "ADULT",
            "fareOptions": [
                "STANDARD"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "sources": [
        "GDS"
    ],
    "searchCriteria": {
        "maxFlightOffers": 1,
        "flightFilters": {
            "maxFlightTime": 110,
            "cabinRestrictions": [
                {
                    "cabin": "ECONOMY",
                    "coverage": "MOST_SEGMENTS",
                    "originDestinationIds": [
                        "1"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

This is the response you will get:
`MAD` to `DFW` for a duration of `PT10H35M` (10h35) and then `DAL` (another Dallas Airport?) to `SFO` for a duration of
`PT4H4M` (4h04) so a total duration of 14h39.

This is why `maxFlightTime` can only be between 100 and 999.

The API specification is not very clear for this parameter, we will update it very soon.